# Sums of powers being powers of the sum

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I'm looking for literature on solving problems of the form
$$
n_1^\alpha+\cdots+n_k^\alpha=(n_1+\cdots+n_k)^\beta
$$
for positive integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ and fixed parameters $k$ and $\alpha\ne\beta.$ Any ideas?

This is perhaps similar to multigrade equations or "equal sums of like powers" but not quite similar enough to use those results (as far as I can see). But surely this is too simple not to have been studied?

Comment: As a flash idea: what if we take the logarithm 0f both sides, then applying the series expansion of the $ln$ function.

Comment: It is not clear from the statement of the question, whether you require $\alpha$ and/or $\beta$ to be positive integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that $\alpha>\beta$ (if we consider $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{N}$).

$2$ limitations for $(n_1,\ldots, n_k)$:

**A.** Using [generalized mean (power mean)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), one can obtain:

$\dfrac{n_1+\ldots+n_k}{k} \leqslant \sqrt[\alpha]{\dfrac{n_1^{\alpha}+\ldots+n_k^{\alpha}}{k}}$,

$\left(\dfrac{n_1+\ldots+n_k}{k} \right)^\alpha \leqslant \dfrac{n_1^{\alpha}+\ldots+n_k^{\alpha}}{k} = \dfrac{(n_1 + \ldots + n_k)^\beta}{k}$,

$\left(n_1+\ldots+n_k \right)^{\alpha-\beta} \leqslant k^{\alpha-1}$.

So, limitation for sum:
\begin{array}{|c|} \hline
n_1+\ldots+n_k\leqslant k^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha-\beta}}. \\ \hline \end{array}

If we'll consider the case $\beta = \alpha-1$, then    $n_1+\ldots+n_k\leqslant k^{\alpha-1}$.

**B.**
We can obtain other (more strong) limitation:

$\dfrac{n_1+\ldots+n_k}{k}\leqslant\sqrt[\beta]{\dfrac{n_1^\beta+\ldots+n_k^\beta}{k}} \leqslant \sqrt[\alpha]{\dfrac{n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha}{k}}$,

$\dfrac{n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha}{k^\beta} = \left(\dfrac{n_1+\ldots+n_k}{k}\right)^\beta \leqslant \dfrac{n_1^\beta+\ldots+n_k^\beta}{k} \leqslant \left(\dfrac{n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha}{k}\right)^{\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}$,

$\left(n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha\right)^{\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha}} \leqslant k^{\beta - \frac{\beta}{\alpha}} = k^{\frac{(\alpha-1)\beta}{\alpha}}$.

So, limitation for power sum:
\begin{array}{|c|} \hline
n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha\leqslant k^{\frac{(\alpha-1)\beta}{\alpha-\beta}}.
\\ \hline \end{array}

If we'll consider the case $\beta = \alpha-1$, then    $n_1^\alpha+\ldots+n_k^\alpha\leqslant k^{(\alpha-1)\beta}$.

---

A few examples (for different $n_1, n_2,\ldots,n_k$):

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(3,2), \;\;k\in \mathbb{N}}$: a famous identity:
$\color{#CC3300}{1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^3 = (1+2+\ldots+k)^2}$.

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \;\;k=5}$:
$6^4+7^4+12^4+15^4+19^4=(6+7+12+15+19)^3$;

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \;\;k=6}$:
$2^4+9^4+14^4+21^4+22^4+23^4=(2+9+14+21+22+23)^3$;
$4^4+5^4+6^4+11^4+13^4+20^4=(4+5+6+11+13+20)^3$;

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \;\;k=7}$:
$(1,2,11,14,17,20,26)$;
$(1,8,12,22,23,28,29)$;
$(1,22,23,26,29,33,39)$;
$(3,11,18,21,26,27,35)$;
$(5,9,16,20,26,30,33)$;
$(5,10,11,19,23,24,33)$;
$(6,7,18,21,25,31,33)$;
$\ldots$

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \;\;k=6}$:
$1^5+3^5+14^5+21^5+22^5+39^5 = (1+3+14+21+22+39)^4$;
$3^5+57^5+81^5+96^5+99^5+114^5 = (3+57+81+96+99+114)^4$;
$4^5+45^5+57^5+90^5+91^5+98^5 = (4+45+57+90+91+98)^4$;
$\ldots$

$\color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \;\;k=7}$:

$1^5+2^5+27^5+38^5+54^5+69^5+80^5 = (1+2+27+38+54+69+80)^4$;
$1^5+5^5+17^5+26^5+34^5+59^5+63^5 = (1+5+17+26+34+59+63)^4$;
$2^5+20^5+23^5+36^5+38^5+43^5+79^5 = (2+20+23+36+38+43+79)^4$;
$3^5+4^5+12^5+16^5+17^5+45^5+48^5 = (3+4+12+16+17+45+48)^4$;
$3^5+18^5+19^5+27^5+35^5+37^5+71^5 = (3+18+19+27+35+37+71)^4$;
$\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about the literature, but it is clear that for each $k,$ there is only finitely many solutions. Clearly, $\alpha>\beta.$ Assuming that $n_1\le n_2...\le n_k$ we can estimate, $(kn_k)^{\beta}\ge RHS=LHS\ge n_k^{\alpha},$ hence
$n_k^{\alpha-\beta}\le k^{\beta}.$

Comment: I agree that there are finitely many solutions for each triple. I'd like to be able to find results about whether there will be any and how many there are for differing $k$ values. (Or whatever else has been proved...)

Comment: Looking at the examples, provided by Oleg567, I am getting less ambitious about a nice description of how many solutions we have in general. Of course, in some particular cases, from what I wrote above one can easily extract some useful information. For example, if $k^{\frac{\beta}{\alpha-\beta}}<c$ for "small" $c,$ one can check potential solutions by hands...

Answer (score 1):

... Continuation:

A list of solutions for certain $(\alpha,\beta)$, $k$:

\begin{array}{|c|l|c|}
\hline
(\alpha, \beta), \; k & (n_1, \ldots, n_k) & n_1+\ldots+n_k \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=1}
& \color{#CC3300}{1} & \color{#CC3300}{1} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=2}
& \color{#CC3300}{(4,4)} & \color{#CC3300}{8} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=3}
& \color{#CC3300}{(9,9,9)} & \color{#CC3300}{27} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=4} 
& (7,14,14,14) & 49 \\ 
& \color{#CC3300}{(16,16,16,16)} & \color{#CC3300}{64} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=5}
& (5,15,15,20,20) & 75 \\
& (6,7,12,15,19) &  59 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(25,25,25,25,25)} & \color{#CC3300}{125} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=6}
& (2,2,2,8,8,14) & 36 \\
& (2,9,14,21,22,23) & 91 \\
& (3,3,7,13,16,19) & 61 \\
& (4,5,6,11,13,20) & 59 \\
& (28,32,32,32,36,40) & 200 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(36,36,36,36,36,36)} & \color{#CC3300}{216} \\
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(4,3), \; k=7}
& (1,1,2,4,7,14,14) & 43 \\
& (1,2,11,14,17,20,26) & 91 \\
& (1,5,6,6,11,11,21) & 61 \\
& (1,8,12,22,23,28,29) & 123 \\
& (1,22,23,26,29,33,39) & 173 \\
& (2,2,4,12,12,14,22) & 68 \\
& (2,14,14,14,23,23,33) & 123 \\
& (3,11,18,21,26,27,35) & 141 \\
& (3,18,21,27,30,36,36) & 171 \\
& (4,12,14,14,14,28,30) & 116 \\
& (5,7,15,23,23,31,31) & 135 \\
& (5,9,16,20,26,30,33) & 139 \\
& (5,10,11,19,23,24,33) & 125 \\
& (6,7,18,21,25,31,33) & 141 \\
& (6,12,21,32,32,33,35) & 171 \\
& (6,16,16,18,24,34,34) & 148 \\
& (7,7,9,9,12,22,27) & 93 \\
& (7,8,8,8,9,10,25) & 75 \\
& (7,9,9,9,17,23,29) & 103 \\
& (8,11,24,25,32,34,37) & 171 \\
& (9,9,16,17,19,20,35) & 125 \\
& (9,10,22,24,26,32,38) & 161 \\
& (9,12,24,24,30,33,39) & 171 \\
& (10,19,30,33,33,37,43) & 205 \\
& (10,21,21,22,24,31,42) & 171 \\
& (10,21,33,36,39,40,40) & 219 \\
& (13,16,17,26,27,33,41) & 173 \\
& (13,16,19,22,27,37,39) & 173 \\
& (13,17,20,22,24,34,41) & 171 \\
& (13,21,31,35,38,39,44) & 221 \\
& (15,20,24,25,26,32,45) & 187 \\
& (17,17,25,30,33,39,44) & 205 \\
& (17,18,22,31,33,38,44) & 203 \\
& (18,19,24,24,26,38,44) & 193 \\
& (18,26,37,40,41,42,47) & 251 \\
& (19,20,29,31,36,39,47) & 221 \\
& (21,21,25,28,41,41,44) & 221 \\
& (21,28,36,39,39,39,51) & 253 \\
& (22,27,32,36,40,47,47) & 251 \\
& (22,30,30,44,44,44,46) & 260 \\
& (25,25,29,30,35,44,49) & 237 \\
& (25,33,35,40,41,42,53) & 269 \\
& (27,36,37,39,46,46,52) & 283 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(49,49,49,49,49,49,49)} & \color{#CC3300}{343} \\
\hline 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=1}
& \color{#CC3300}{1} & \color{#CC3300}{1} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=2}
& \color{#CC3300}{(8,8)} & \color{#CC3300}{8} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=3}
& \color{#CC3300}{(27,27,27)} & \color{#CC3300}{27} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=4} 
& (22,22,33,44) & 121 \\
& (50,50,60,65) & 225 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(64,64,64,64)} & \color{#CC3300}{256} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=5} 
& (36,36,36,36,72) & 216 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(125,125,125,125,125)} & \color{#CC3300}{625} \\ 
\hline \color{#003388}{(\alpha,\beta)=(5,4), \; k=6} 
& (1,3,14,21,22,39) & 100 \\
& (3,57,81,96,99,114) & 450 \\
& (4,45,57,90,91,98) & 385 \\
& (5,5,40,45,57,68) & 220 \\
& (7,60,80,85,85,118) & 435 \\
& (10,25,41,55,55,84) & 270 \\
& (14,31,36,44,44,81) & 250 \\
& (16,56,64,64,88,112) & 400 \\
& (18,36,45,72,81,99) & 351 \\
& (21,38,45,75,92,99) & 370 \\
& (25,60,85,115,115,125) & 525 \\
& (30,35,52,77,88,108) & 390 \\
& (30,81,113,115,138,139) & 616 \\
& (34,68,80,110,112,136) & 540 \\
& (35,45,55,75,75,115) & 400 \\
& (36,40,68,82,112,113) & 451 \\
& \color{#CC3300}{(216,216,216,216,216,216)} & \color{#CC3300}{1296} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}