# When is the power of a binomial equal to the sum of like powers of its terms?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

**Question:** Under what circumstances/restrictions on $x$ and $y$ does $(x + y)^n = x^n + y^n$ given the value of $n$? That is, what can we tell about $x$ and $y$ from the value of $n$ and the equation $(x + y)^n = x^n + y^n$? I'd be satisfied with $ x, y \in \mathbb{Z} $ and $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.

**Background:** Spivak's Calculus' Question 1-16 asks us to find the restrictions  individually from $n = 1$ till $n = 5$; and invited readers to guess at the general pattern for any $n$, which I still couldn't see.

---

**Research:**  This is a subset of [Sums of powers being powers of the sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398590/sums-of-powers-being-powers-of-the-sum) where $ \alpha = \beta $ and $ k = 2 $; but I want a more specific and simpler explanations.

**Edit:** The original, ambiguous framing of this question was interpreted by  commenters to mean asking about the limitations on $n$ to satisfy $ (x + y)^n = x^n + y^n $ for any $x$ and $y$. I have since edited it to (hopefully) better reflect my original intent; and apologize to the answerers.

Comment: $n=1$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you mean "would the equation ... be true for **every** $n \in N$"?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream) might be interesting.

Comment: @YatharthROCK Obviously, for the conditions you stated n=1 is the only solution.

Comment: @Awesome: Aah... thanks, I finally realize the discrepancy between my intent of asking the question and how it was originally framed (see my edit).

Answer (score 5):

$$(x+y)^n=x^n+y^n$$
By the Binomial Theorem we can expand the left side to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}}x^{n-k}y^k=x^n+y^n$$
Isolate the $x^n$ and $y^n$ by changing the bounds on the summation.
$$x^n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{k}}x^{n-k}y^k+y^n=x^n+y^n$$
Thus the two sides are equal when
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{k}}x^{n-k}y^k=0$$
Notice that, if $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\binom{n}{k}}x^{n-k}y^k$ is strictly positive and only $n=1$ is a solution.  Relaxing to $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ give more possibilities of solutions. For example, if $x=1, y=-1$, then the equation is satisfied for $n=2m-1$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive answer; but apologies for [realizing the discrepancy between my intent of asking the question and how it was originally framed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/788884/revisions) so late. Could you still answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to show from the binomial theorem, that for every $n\neq1$, the equation has solutions only if $x=0\lor y=0$, because otherwise we come up with additional not-null terms (and binomial terms are always positive)

(That assuming $n\in\mathbb{N}$, however that question would be much more interesting if $x,y,n \in \mathbb{R}$, but I wouldn't have the necessary knowledge to answer you. Indeed I suspect the solution is the same...)

Comment: +1 for the answer; but apologies for [realizing the discrepancy between my intent of asking the question and how it was originally framed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/788884/revisions) so late. Could you still answer the question?